# Passing data between WebAPI and WebForms

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I'm currently facing the following issue:

I'm working on a website that's mostly using WebForms, but it has an API controller to handle some ajax requests.
When a certain ajax request arrives on the controller, I need to save a bit of data and put it in the next WebForms page that is being rendered.

This is not a request for best practices advice or architectural improvements.

I tried saving the data as a session variable, but I keep getting NullReferenceExceptions in the WebAPI controller.

Is there any way to pass session-bound data easily? Any hack is fine, this just needs to work.

Edit:
The specific workflow is the following:
On the shopping cart page (WebForm) you are able to add products by productid, which is handled via ajax. When the product is already in the cart I need to let the user know about that, but this information is ONLY available in the WebAPI controller (where the ajax request goes).
Right after the ajax response arrives, the page is reloaded via location.reload(); to update the shopping cart, which prompts the WebForm to re-render serverside. This is where I need to access the information that was stored in the previous ajax request, and write it out to the WebForms page.

Comment: Can you please show your implementation?

Comment: I would like to, but the codebase is too cluttered/big. I edited my post to contain a more detailled workflow.